# How are the relative abundances of isotopes of elements on Earth estimated?

Tags: elements

"For example,
of all the hydrogen isotopes on Earth, 99.985% occur as
an isotope without a neutron and 0.015% as an isotope with
1 neutron. There is a third isotope with 2 neutrons, and is
even more rare."
How do we know this?

Answer (score 0):

We can easily measure the deuterium and tritium abundance in seawater using a mass spectrometer, and we assume that the abundances in seawater are representative of the Earth in general. The figures you quote are the abundances in seawater.

This is probably a reasonable safe assumption. We believe the young Earth was so hot that it boiled off most of the water it originally had, and all the water was then supplied by cometary impacts. Though I believe there is some debate on this topic - if you want to pursue this maybe ask on the [Earth Sciences Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

We also know that seawater is cycled through the mantle by subduction, so we would expect the water in the mantle and in the seas to have the same isotopic abundances.

Answer (score 0):

This would be determined in a chemistry lab by running samples of hydrogen through a mass spectrometer, which would separate the isotopes and furnish relative percentages of each.

The mass differences would be apparent in the physics lab before the invention of mass spectrometers by experiments involving the use of (ionized) hydrogen as a proton source to feed an accelerator, where the mass difference would be apparent whenever the resulting proton beam had to be electrostatically deflected- at which time it would split into a triplet.